# how to get a spotlight in opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl

reference
http://www.chai3d.org/doc/classc_light.html

code

```
    light2->setPos(cVector3d( 0, 0,0.0));  // position the light source
    light2->m_ambient.set(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
    light2->m_diffuse.set(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
    light2->m_specular.set(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
    light2->setDirectionalLight(false);//make a positional light
```

the rendering code which uses opengl is

```
void cLight::renderLightSource()
{
    // check if light source enabled
    if (m_enabled == false)
    {
        // disable OpenGL light source
        glDisable(m_glLightNumber);
        return;
    }

    computeGlobalCurrentObjectOnly();

    // enable this light in OpenGL
    glEnable(m_glLightNumber);

    // set lighting components
    glLightfv(m_glLightNumber, GL_AMBIENT,  m_ambient.pColor());
    glLightfv(m_glLightNumber, GL_DIFFUSE,  m_diffuse.pColor() );
    glLightfv(m_glLightNumber, GL_SPECULAR, m_specular.pColor());

    // position the light source in (global) space (because we're not
    // _rendered_ as part of the scene graph)
    float position[4];

    position[0] = (float)m_globalPos.x;
    position[1] = (float)m_globalPos.y;
    position[2] = (float)m_globalPos.z;
    //position[0] = (float)m_localPos.x;
    //position[1] = (float)m_localPos.y;
    //position[2] = (float)m_localPos.z;

    // Directional light source...
    if (m_directionalLight) position[3] = 0.0f;

    // Positional light source...
    else position[3] = 1.0f;

    glLightfv(m_glLightNumber, GL_POSITION, (const float *)&position);

    // set cutoff angle
    glLightf(m_glLightNumber, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, m_cutOffAngle);

    // set the direction of my light beam, if I'm a _positional_ spotlight
    if (m_directionalLight == false)
    {
        cVector3d dir = m_globalRot.getCol0();
        float direction[4];
        direction[0] = (float)dir.x;
        direction[1] = (float)dir.y;
        direction[2] = (float)dir.z;
        direction[3] = 0.0f;
        glLightfv(m_glLightNumber, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, (const float *)&direction);
    }

    // set attenuation factors
    glLightf(m_glLightNumber, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, m_attConstant);
    glLightf(m_glLightNumber, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, m_attLinear);
    glLightf(m_glLightNumber, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, m_attQuadratic);

    // set exponent factor
    glLightf(m_glLightNumber, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, m_spotExponent);    
}
```

why do I get my whole environment uniformly lighted?
how do I get a concetrated light around the origin 0,0,0, which fades away after 1 or 2 unit distance? My origin is the middle cube in the grid.[image]

Comment: This isn't really a OpenGL related question because you are using a existing framework. Also, i don't have the time to look into the framework and check how it works. If the framework uses the fixed function pipeline you need to enable lighting before using lights.

Comment: Check if the following flags are enabled:  
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);  
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

Comment: Maybe the light is to close to the points, try to set the light to a far position.

Comment: doesnt make a difference, can I reduce the intensity?

Comment: I really don't know how the fixed function pipeline works. It's a shame that so many frameworks are still supporting the ffp.

Comment: you are using deprecated functions, it's like asking how you can live in this century like a person from the 1700.

Answer (score 1):

caveat emptor: This is "from the top of my head" from way-back-when i used to fumble with OpenGL.

I think the OpenGL concept of a "directional light" is sort of like a point-lightsource at infinity, meaning the light-vector is invariant across the entire scene.

In order to do the spotlight effect, you need to form the dot-product of the light-direction and the light-vector (vector from vertex to light) and attenuate the light exponentially as the angle increases.

I remember reading a tutorial about this once, will search...

Right, its described [here](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html)
Scroll down to the description of "spotlights".

In the code you've listed, I believe you need to ensure that `m_spotExponent` is greater-than zero to get a "cone" effect. Higher values yield a "sharper" transition from "lit" to "dark" parts of the cone (I think).

Hope that helps